# SSAS Tabular connection error - The server sent an unrecognizable response, XmlException 0x06 is an invalid character

Tags: c#, ssas, ssas-tabular, xmlexception

I'm trying to connect to an Analysis Services Server with some C#. The server is using the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular` Assembly namespace (SSAS Tabular). Here's my code:

```
using var server = new Server();
server.Connect(myConnectionString);
var db = server.Databases.FindByName("MyAnalysisServer");
...
```

The code breaks on the second line where it tries to `Connect`. *The weird thing is*, this worked for a good couple of months, but all of a sudden started generating an error. We haven't changed the connection string whatsoever. The Exception User-Unhandled that pops up is:

> **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ResponseFormatException**: The server sent an unrecognizable response.
>
> Inner Exception
>
> XmlException:", hexadecimalvalue 0x06, is an invalid character.
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code]

The connection string is formatted in this way:

`Provider=MSOLAP;datasource=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myFunctions/My Function;initial catalog=MyAnalysisServer;User ID=app:12345678-eee-0000-0000-123456789012@12345678-1234-5678-1234-123456789012;Password=qwertyui~12345678`

I'm really not sure what the issue could be, but if anyone has any ideas, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a useless error message, but I'll bet the root cause is an authentication problem such as an expired password or locked account.

See here for a nice write up:
https://www.koskila.net/connecting-to-site-failed-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-invalid-character-when-trying-to-connect-to-sharepoint-online/

Comment: This was the issue, thanks for posting and including the awesome write up link.